# Jenkins child job to take parameters from parent job and trigger same child job multiple times for different parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins child job to take parameters from parent job and trigger same child job multiple times for different parameters.
 can we do this with any plugin?
please help?

Comment: Any idea, if we can achieve this with a plugin?